# Applying SimpleImputer and OneHotEncoder to multiple columns at once

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am applying the following code to impute and then encode categorical data in my dataset:

```py
    # Encoding categorical data
    # Define a Pipeline with an imputing step using SimpleImputer prior to the OneHot encoding
    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

    # use strategy='constant', fill_value='missing' for imputing to preserve the categories' structure
    categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
        ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ('cat', categorical_transformer, [0])
        ])

    Z = np.array(preprocessor.fit_transform(Z))

    print (Z[:,0])
```

I want to repeat these steps for all columns in the array Z, as Z is comprised of all categorical features from my original dataset. 
Is there a more efficient way of doing this rather than listing each column as such:

```py
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
    ])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all columns have the same type, I would simply omit the `ColumnTransformer` and use a simple pipeline in your case:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder


# some sample data
X = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3'],
    'col2': [np.nan, 'oj3', 'oj1'],
    'col3': ['jo3', 'jo1', np.nan]
}).astype('category')
y = pd.Series([0, 1, 1])

pipeline = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='constant', fill_value='missing'),
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
)

Z = pipeline.fit_transform(X, y)
```

The `ColumnTransformer` is meant to be used for heterogeneous data when columns or column subsets of the input need to be transformed separately (read [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html?highlight=columntransformer#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer)). However, since your features are all of the same type and all require the same preprocessing procedure, you can just apply `SimpleImputer` and `OneHotEncoder` to the whole dataset as these transformers will automatically detect the columns to transform (which in your case are simply all).